# What to put for the alsaaudio python card？

Tags: python, ubuntu, a-records, pyalsaaudio

I am trying to use alsaaudio in my python code.

`inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK, card)`

For the third parameter `card`, what should I put?

```
root@abc:~/Desktop# arecord --list-devices
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: H340 [Logitech USB Headset H340], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I want to input audio from the Logitech USB Headset.
Should it be `hw:1,0` ????

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#pcm-objects) says:

> ```
> class alsaaudio.PCM(type=PCM_PLAYBACK, mode=PCM_NORMAL, device='default', cardindex=-1)
> ```
>
> This class is used to represent a PCM device (either for playback and recording). The arguments are:
>   […]
>
> - device - the name of the PCM device that should be used (for example a value from the output of `pcms()`). The default value is `'default'`.
>
> […]
>
> Changed in 0.8:
>
> - The `card` keyword argument is still supported, but deprecated. Please use `device` instead.
> - The keyword argument `cardindex` was added.
>
> The `card` keyword is deprecated because it guesses the real ALSA name of the card. This was always fragile and broke some legitimate usecases.